# Blender Python select vertices of a mesh with their index

Tags: python, blender, mesh, vertex

How can I tell a script to select the vertices of a mesh within their indecies that are stored in a list? For example, "currentFace" contains the verts 6,7,8; these are the verts that create the face.

Now I want to select those vertecies to assign a material to them.

```
mesh.vertices[currentFace].select = True # Select Mesh's currentFace-verts
bpy.ops.object.material_slot_assign() # assign selected material in mesh material-slot to selected verts
```

The console says that lists are not supported. Is there any other way to select the vertices of the mesh within its index?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a list as an index into an array. The way to get it to work is to loop through each value in the list -

```
for i in currentFace:
    mesh.vertices[i].select = True
```